# how to read and write data to nfc tag in ios Application

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc

I would like to implement NFC in my application(NFC implementation is possible using mobile wallet for iphone just like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itaptag/id694873763?mt=8  which is already at AppStore) , can any one please provide me sample code to read and write data to nfc tag for iphone Application

thanks in advance

Comment: Required Accessories
- DeviceFidelity microNFC
- NFC iPhone Sleeve such as the DeviceFidelity iCaisse 4L, iCaisse4X, or the Incipio Cashwrap for iPhone. http://credense.com/api/

Comment: thanks jcesar, is it possible to get DeviceFidelity sdk or Api to use in My Application

Comment: Sure, you can use the API if you purchase the DeviceFidelity Development Kit

Comment: jcesar can u please let me know if there are any free API's available. thanks

Comment: I don't know, but even if you find a free API, you'll need to purchase some accessories like the mentioned on the first comment, as iOS devices don't include NFC

Comment: yes jcesar, i already purchased incipio cashwrap for iphone 4 and i need details to connect the cashwrap programatically to read nfc tag.

Comment: contact the DeviceFidelity team and ask them

Comment: jcesar, i have already did that but i didn't even got any reply from them. will u plz give me any contact mail id of DeviceFidelity team......... thanks for ur valuable reply's

Comment: I don't have any contact mail of DeviceFidelity team, sorry.

Comment: @user2294134 Did you get access to the DeviceFidelity Development Kit?